# How to change the BackGround image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code, background

I am using VS Code not Visual studio.

i am confused how to change the background image in form1desiner(genarated by windows form)

Comment: Your form has a BackgroundImage Property that you can set via the designer or in code. That should be also valid for VS Code. At least the set it in code part.

Comment: can you side open VS "full" to perform such action, highly guided by the IDE ? If it matters, VS "full" has a [free version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/vs/community/)